# Mostrar datos de json a un datatable en php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, datatables

Buenas noches;
Espero puedan ayudarme, tengo un pequeño problema al mostrar los datos dentro de un datatable, los datos si se muestran en el index pero no dentro del datatable.

Este es el código JS dentro de mi index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
                url: 'getjson.php',
                dataType: 'json',
            })

    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.datos, function(i,post){
        var newRow =
        "<tbody>"
        +"<tr>"
        +"<td>"+post.login+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+post.email+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+post.nombre+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+post.apellido+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+post.cargo+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+post.direccion+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+post.gerencia+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+post.jefatura+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+post.jefe_inmediato+"</td>"
        +"</tr>"
        +"</tbody>";
        $(newRow).appendTo("#json-data");
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('Error');
    })
    });
```

Pero al ser llamado desde el la tabla con el id="json-data" los datos lo carga fuera del datatable.

este es mi archivo getjson.php en el cual obtengo los datos de la bd

```
<?php

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $posts = array();
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM user ");

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        //$posts['datos'][] = $row;
        $posts['datos'][] = array_map("utf8_encode", $row);
    }

    echo json_encode($posts);

?>
```

y por ultimo este es el el codigo de la tabla

```
<table id="json-data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Login </th>
                                <th> Email </th>
                                <th> Nombre </th>
                                <th> Apellidos </th>
                                <th> Cargo </th>
                                <th> Dirección </th>
                                <th> Gerencia </th>
                                <th> Jefatura </th>
                                <th> Jefe Inmediato </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

espero me puedan ayudar.